# @font-face not working on Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I'm using the @font-face function to use a custom font (Geosanslight) on my Wordpress site.

I have downloaded the webkit using http://www.fontsquirrel.com and uploaded them into the folder http://www.lynnepassmore.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts.

I have then used the @font-face function in my custom css file to call them. However the font is not visible on any browser.

Here is my @font-face css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'geosanslight';
src: url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/geosanslight-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, a {
font-family: geosanslight !important;
}
```

Comment: Where have you added your `@font-face` CSS?

Comment: Hi Zaq you got a link to your site your font path is probobly wrong

Comment: Into the custom css file under theme options

Comment: www.lynnepassmore.com

Comment: Your styles are being output to your `index.php` file, use an absolute path to point to your font files.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path, could you give me an example?

Comment: http://www.lynnepassmore.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/geosanslight-webfont.eot

Comment: something like that?

Comment: @George could you give me an example..

Answer (score 0):

Your custom css is actually in the source code index, hence the relative path wont work. Change your font paths as follow.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'geosanslight';
src: url('/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/geosanslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, a {
font-family: "geosanslight",sans-serif;
}
```

please make sure your final css is like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'geosanslight';
src: url('/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/geosanslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, a {
font-family: 'geosanslight', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Made the changes you mentioned but still no change

Comment: @ZaqMughal i have updated my answer, there actually the src was missing in some. can u check now. and you dont really need all those format definitions even truetype or woff alone should work on majority of browsers

Comment: Okay so I've added the src and changed the commas for ; and it seems to be working on safari but not on chrome

Comment: @ZaqMughal try whats in the answer now, its working for me in inspector

Comment: @ZaqMughal it is because cross origin headers are missing, the css style loaded is http://www.lynnepassmore.com/wp-content/themes/esteem/style.css?ver=4.2.2 but your website by default redirects the user to non www url. So change the url of your css file to non www if you are going to keep the default site url non www

Comment: hi sorry about late reply. I have changed the site to a www url by changing it in my database but the problem still occurs

Comment: @ZaqMughal I have just updated my answer, you still have the svg format added there too, remove it and make sure your css is as in the answer. It works fine for me with that

Comment: Working now on all other than IE.. Sorry about this but just want it to work across all browsers

Comment: can you try adding back the eot variants? both eot and eot ie fix that you had initially..

Comment: added them both back in above the true type src but still no luck with IE

Answer (score 0):

Check on your browser console :

> Font from origin 'http://www.lynnepassmore.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://lynnepassmore.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

You're trying to load a font from a different domain (www vs without www) - it is considered as a distant resource, and blocked by the headers policy.

You can use relative path for your font if you include it from your css file, then it'll be relative to your **css file** location.

Comment: Okay so I've done this and its all working other than on Google Chrome... Any ideas?

Comment: You should use relative paths: `./fonts/` instead of `/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/`

Comment: Note also that your fontawesome-webfont.ttf path is wrong.

Comment: And will that display it correctly on Google Chrome?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about because the font isn't displaying in Firefox or in any browser for me.