# @font-face not displaying correct font on all browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, browser, fonts, font-face

I have recently developed a Wordpress site using the Esteem theme. On my site I am using a custom font called GeosansLight and to use this font I am using the @font-face css trick.

However, the correct font only seems to be showing up on Safari. When you view the site on Chrome, Firefox or IE the font is incorrect.

Please can someone help as the site is very much based around that font.

Here is the part of my css that calls the @font-face and assigns that font to my various elements:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'geosanslight';
src: url('/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/geosanslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
src: url('/wp-content/themes/esteem/fonts/geosanslight-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, a {
font-family: "geosanslight", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31543364/1716437

Comment: @Zaq Mughal Please avoid to duplicate your own questions - go back on your original question and answer the questions we asked you so we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a lot of font types for `font-face` and the other browsers don't want `svg` or `truetype`.

Take your font to [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

this will generate everything you need for your site including the css and all the font files.

also for your root if you are putting the css in your main style.css in your themes root then all you will need is: `src: url('fonts/geosanslight-webfont.ttf')`